# Making a .js file download a file from the internet?

Tags: javascript, batch-file, download

I have a batch program that I'm coding. I've made it make a file called "filedownload.js". I need THAT "filedownload.js" to be able to download a file

```
http://www.batchfilegamescontent.elementfx.com/examplefile.txt
```

to a specific folder. Eg;

```
C:\Users\%Username%\desktop\RamTach\data\
```

then I need the batch file to run the "filedownload.js" file. Could I do so using

```
md ".settings"
call filedownload.js
```

??
on the "filedownload.js" would

```
setTimeout(function () { window.location =    'http://www.batchfilegamescontent.elementfx.com/examplefile.txt'; }, 0)
```

work?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to download files from the internet is using my application called MGet that downloads files and it doesn't have hard syntax.
URL: http://bit.ly/1i1FpGE
Syntax:

```
MGET http://www.batchfilegamescontent.elementfx.com/examplefile.txt examplefile.txt
```

Comment: that would go on the batch file, or the javascript file?

Comment: it is its own application. Try it it will download that file and it will be downloaded in '%cd%' folder.(That is the current folder)

Comment: And why use JAVASCRIPT? VBS is easier!

Comment: so what file extension do I use?

Comment: .bat or .cmd extension

Comment: i created the application myself. Do you like it?

Comment: And why use http://www.batchfilegamescontent.elementfx.com/examplefile.txt it says Error 404 (Page not found)

Comment: Just because it's a free host for my files

Comment: Oh ok. I can't register to x10host because i am from Macedonia :( Did the application work?

Comment: It "worked" but I'm having a hard time using it. When I do

        call mget.bat

it makes the program I have freeze

Comment: create a file named anything else than MGET name it download.bat because the download file doesn't know what to use (itself or mget.exe)

Comment: Now when I run it, it's named "filedownload.cmd" it says "mget isn't recognized as an internal or external command"

Comment: Did you put mget.exe to the same folder?

Comment: i've done it, and now it says the syntax is incorrect

Comment: Did you use it like this: MGET [URL TO DOWNLOAD] [SAVE AS]

Comment: did it again with the correct syntax, now I get that the website doesn't used a recognized protocal

Comment: Oh and i have no idea why doesn't work with your url it worked for:
http://www.realmofthemadgod.com/version.txt version.txt
mget http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23184499/making-a-js-file-download-a-file-from-the-internet/23184616 page.html

Comment: Yes:
`@echo off
mget http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23184499/making-a-js-file-download-a-file-from-the-internet/23184616 page.html
pause > nul`

Comment: Wait the code didn't show like i expected!
@echo off
mget http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23184499/making-a-js-file-download-a-file-fro‌​m-the-internet/23184616 page.html
pause >nul

Comment: Do mget ..blablabla-url... c:\SAVE.txt

Comment: Ok, it works, but I'm still getting an error
"the system cannot find the file path specified"

Comment: Dose it saves it in the folder? If it dose don't worry. It says that because it cant find it in the temp folder! It moves it from the temp folder to your started folder!

Comment: No, it doesn't save it to the folder.

Comment: Well don't use C:\SAVE.txt just use SAVE.txt and in the begging of the file after `@echo off` do `cd C:\Folder` and it will save it in C:\Folder ok?

Comment: It still doesn't work. Still getting the same error.

Comment: I figured it out. It's cuz there was no content written on the file. Fixed. Thanks!

Comment: Just use the old code please! I will try to fix it!

Answer (score 0):

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /****** silent line that start jscript comment ******

@echo off
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:::       compile the script    ::::
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
setlocal
if exist simpledownloader.exe goto :skip_compilation

set "frm=%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\"
:: searching the latest installed .net framework
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%v in ('dir /b /s /a:d /o:-n "%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v*"') do (
    if exist "%%v\jsc.exe" (
        rem :: the javascript.net compiler
        set "jsc=%%~dpsnfxv\jsc.exe"
        goto :break_loop
    )
)
echo jsc.exe not found && exit /b 0
:break_loop


call %jsc% /nologo /out:"simpledownloader.exe" "%~dpsfnx0"
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:::       end of compilation    ::::
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:skip_compilation

:: download the file


 ::::just change the link and the file::::
 simpledownloader.exe "http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=id7CWRHF" "target.bat"


exit /b 0


****** end of jscript comment ******/

import System;
var arguments:String[] = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
var webClient:System.Net.WebClient = new System.Net.WebClient();
print("Downloading " + arguments[1] + " to " + arguments[2]);
try {
    webClient.DownloadFile(arguments[1], arguments[2]);
} catch (e) {

        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.WriteLine("\n\nProblem with downloading " + arguments[1] + " to " + arguments[2] + "Check if the internet address is valid");
        Console.ResetColor();
        Environment.Exit(5);
}
```

Check this. Will without any external tools.Save it as a `.bat`.This should download your file .Just change the link and the target

Comment: I like this code, but is there anyway to make my original batch file write each line to the new .bat file without having to individually do
to 'echo' each line?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use javascript you can try this using node.js:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var file = fs.createWriteStream(your_path);
var request = http.get(your_url, function(response) {
  response.pipe(file);
});
```

Then to run `node <scriptname>.js`